# Deep learning: big difference between training and validation loss from the very first epoch on

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, convolution

My neural net is slightly modified version of model proposed on this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01781.pdf

My goal is to classify text to 9 different categories. I'm using 29 convolutional layers and have set the max length of any text to 256 characters.

Training data has 900k and validation data 35k samples. The data is quite imbalanced and therefore I have done some data augmentation to balance the training data (have not touched the validation data obviously) and then used class weights in training.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 256, 16)           1152      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 256, 64)           3136      
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_2 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_3 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_4 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_5 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_6 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_7 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_8 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_9 (Sequential)    (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_10 (Sequential)   (None, 256, 64)           25216     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 128, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_11 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          75008     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_12 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_13 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_14 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_15 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_16 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_17 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_18 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_19 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_20 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128)          99584     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 64, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_21 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 256)           297472    
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_22 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 256)           395776    
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_23 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 256)           395776    
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_24 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 256)           395776    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 32, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_25 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 512)           1184768   
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_26 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 512)           1577984   
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_27 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 512)           1577984   
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_28 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 512)           1577984   
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2048)              8390656   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2048)              4196352   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 9)                 18441     
=================================================================
Total params: 21,236,681
Trainable params: 21,216,713
Non-trainable params: 19,968
```

With given model I'm receiving the following results:
[image: acc and loss]

For me, the loss curves look weirdish, because I can't spot the typical overfitting effect on the curves, but still the difference between training and validation loss is huge. Also the training loss is way lower at epoch#1 than validation loss is at any epoch.

Is this something I should be worried about and how could I improve my model?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this gap is referred to as the generalisation error :)

Answer (score 1):

To close the gap between training and validation error, i would suggest two things:

- try using more data, if you can find
- use dropout layers in between dense layers for regularization