# Is there other ways to Reducing generalisation error?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science

Hi I am modelling a linear regression model more description can be found here [My stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224353/is-my-training-data-set-too-complex-for-my-neural-network) and I am trying to reduce my Generalization error. Generalization error is the gap between train error and val error according to this post [Stack post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023032/deep-learning-big-difference-between-training-and-validation-loss-from-the-very/51023475#51023475). From my stack post many suggested I regularize and add drop out layers.

I tried all of the methods it helps me to not overfit, but there is no way i can seems to reduce the loss, MAE and MSE.

Things i have tried but don’t know much about (kernal regularize(l1,l2, and L1_l2), and [this post with different ways to reduce error](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-regularization-to-reduce-overfitting-and-improve-generalization-error/) .Things i haven’t tried ( weight constraint and adding noise)

Is there anything i can do to further reduce my loss/generalization error and MAE or MSE?

My model:

```
    def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu ,activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01), input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
        layers.Dropout(.2),
        layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu ,input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
        layers.Dropout(.2),
        layers.Dense(1)
    ])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.005)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
return model
```

results can be found here [train error and val error graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5c8.png) and here [model results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpMXd.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below methods to prevent overfitting:

1. Get more data, if possible
2. Limit your model's complexity so that it can't fit the idiosyncrasies of the data you have. With neural networks, this can be accomplished by limiting the number of hidden layers and/or the number of units per layer.
3. weight decay: penalize large weights using penalties on their squared values (L2) or absolute values (L1)
4. adding Gaussian noise to inputs
5. Average many different models
6. Use different models with different forms
7. Train model on different subsets of the training data ("bagging")
8. Use a single neural network architecture, but learn different sets of weights, and average the predictions across these different sets of weights